# Anchor-based and anchor-free in object detection

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection

As I understand, anchor-based is using multiple box at once to predict bounding box close to ground truth.
1. Is it correct?
 
2. And what is anchor-free?
3. What is the difference between anchor-based and anchor-free (methods, pros, cons,...)?
I'm new and thanks for any answer!

Comment: [This tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/anchor-boxes-for-object-detection.html) from MathWorks team is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following paper is providing a quick overview which you might be interested in. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9233610

Comment: I couldn't even download the paper you mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that there are some approaches to finding bounding boxes. These are categorized as

- `Sliding window`: Consider all possible bounding boxes
- `Anchor-based`: Get a way to find prior knowledge on what widths and heights are more suitable for every class type (it is basically the same as learning common aspect ratios for each class). Then tile those bounding boxes in the image and just predict the probability of those tiles.
  **YOLOv5** uses clustering to estimate anchor-boxes before training and saves them. With that said, it does have its disadvantages. The first is that you must learn anchor-boxes for each class. The second is that your accuracy may be based on your anchor box prediction.
- `Anchor-free`: Instead of using prior knowledge or considering all possibilities, they predict two points (top-left and bottom-right) for every object directly.

Yolov3, Yolov4 and Yolov5 use anchors but YOLOX and CornerNet don't.

Though not a complete explanation, I think you get the point.

References:

- [Anchor Boxes for Object Detection](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/anchor-boxes-for-object-detection.html)
- [A fully convolutional anchor-free object detector](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00371-021-02357-2)
- [Forget the hassles of Anchor boxes with FCOS: Fully Convolutional One-Stage Object Detection](https://towardsdatascience.com/forget-the-hassles-of-anchor-boxes-with-fcos-fully-convolutional-one-stage-object-detection-fc0e25622e1c?gi=20243e9b6827)